# how to write Data to /usr/libexec/cups/filter/ outside the sandbox

Tags: swift, macos, appstore-sandbox

I have an application in the sandbox (for App Store deployment) which needs to install one file into /usr/libexec/cups/filter/ and two file into /private/etc/cups/ . This installation is not done regularly but when executed from UI. Is this possible when demanding "Full Disk Access" or by other means?

```
    var inFilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "thnucups", withExtension: nil, subdirectory: "thnuclnt/x86_64-darwin")!

    let inFile: FileHandle? = try! FileHandle(forReadingFrom: inFilePath)

    let data = inFile?.readDataToEndOfFile()

    inFile?.closeFile()

    var destPath = "/usr/libexec/cups/filter/test";

    let outFileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: destPath)

    FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: destPath, contents: nil, attributes: nil)

    let outFile: FileHandle? = try! FileHandle(forWritingTo: outFileUrl)

    outFile?.write(data!)

    outFile?.closeFile()
```

let outFile: FileHandle? = try! FileHandle(forWritingTo: outFileUrl) throws the following exception:

2019-07-29 15:16:46.985094+0200 ezeep Connector for macOS [33450:488523] Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “test” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/usr/libexec/cups/filter/test, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c5e610 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}: file /Users/rwelz/Documents/Develop/PROJEKTE/ThinPrint/in GIT/ThinPrint/EZEEP/Xcode/ezeep Connector for macOS/ezeep Connector for macOS/AppDelegate.swift, line 146

---

Now with:

```
    let dialog = NSOpenPanel()

    dialog.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    dialog.canCreateDirectories = false
    dialog.canChooseDirectories = true
    dialog.canChooseFiles = false

    dialog.begin
    { (result) -> Void in
        if result == .OK
        {
            let url = dialog.url

            do
            {
                try data?.write(to: outFileUrl)
            }
            catch
            {
                print("Error: Exception caught: " + error.localizedDescription)

            }
        }
    }
```

I am not getting the exception anymore but since /usr/libexec/cups/filter has drwxr-xr-x  root  wheel (no access rights to write when not running as root) I am getting "You don’t have permission to save the file “test” in the folder filter"

I need to run as root which is not allowed in sandbox.

Any other ideas?

regards
Robert

Comment: Btw: ls -l /usr/libexec/cups is 
drwxr-xr-x  24 root  wheel   768B 29 Jul 16:13 filter/
and
ls -l /private/etc/cups
drwxr-xr-x  14 root  _lp     448B  7 Jun 08:12 cups/

Answer (score 0):

I decided to build a pkg installer which can be saved to disk from a menu item in my sandboxed application. The save dialog is also offered when app starts first time. Then the user must open the pkg and and authenticate as admin to start installation. In the pkg's postflight script it sends an apple event to the application ( osascript -e 'tell application PATH to start_action' to let application know that it can proceed.

In fact the installer installs a dummy ppd together with the cups filter into /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/ and my application queries cups for this printer driver (respective the ppd) to make sure /usr/libexec/cups/filer/my_filter is installed.

Now lets see what apple thinks about that solution when reviewing my app ;)